# Is there a reason someone would choose GPLv2 instead of GPLv3?

Tags: licensing, gpl

Is there any reason anyone would use GPL v2 over GPL v3 when starting a new project, or is GPL v2 still around only because older projects can't or haven't updated their license yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use GPL v3 you give up your right to assert patents you have on the technology.

If you own patents and want to monetize these, don't distribute your patented code under GPL v3.